# How do you store values into arrays with a changing size?

Tags: java, arrays

I am fairly new to the concept of arrays, and am currently working on a project that takes user input to find number of values to process (length of array = *num*), minimum value (*min*), and increment (*increment*). I've put the array into a for loop and done the += function to add increment. But, it looks like the index keeps returning to 0, hence not changing the array. The output just prints the first iteration *num* times. Is this the proper way to store arrays with a user-subjective size? Thank you!

```
     double [] x = new double[num]; // initializing array
     x[0] = min;

     for (int index = 0;index <= num; index++) {
         x[index] += increment;
         System.out.println("x: " + x[index]);
     } // for array
```

Comment: Are you sure `increment` isn't just zero?

Comment: Im using num = 10, min = 0, and increment = 0.25 to test. My results are just x = 0.25 10 times

Comment: If every index is zero, and you add `.25` to every index, why would every index not be `.25`?

Comment: That makes sense. But why is every index zero when my for loop has the index++ after every iteration?

Comment: It's not the index that is zero, it is what is *at* `index` that is zero

Comment: To elaborate, your array looks like `[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]`. Then you loop over every spot in the array and add `.25` to every index. At the end it will look like `[0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]`

Comment: Ahhh, so like what is currently stored in the array? Because I think Java defaults empty arrays to 0. How then would I store x[num] based on user input? Is the x[index] function not storing x[1], x[2], etc with new values based on the code inside the loop?

Comment: Ohh I think I figured it out. Instead of using the += increment, could I say something like x[index] = increment * index-1 ? Something to add the previous value onto the existing value.

Comment: `x[index]` points to the `index`'th position of `x`. I'm not really sure what you are trying to do here

Comment: I'm essentially trying to fill each index x[1], x[2], until x[num] (whatever the user inputs). So using x[index] doesn't actually fill that array with a value, it just points to which value it is at? Sorry if this is confusing, this concept is still pretty new to me.

Comment: Well let's say you have `int[] x = new int[3];`, and then you say `x[0] = 2;`. Now your array will be `[2, 0, 0]`. `x[0]` references the first spot of the array, and you set that value to two. In your loop you are incrementing index, such that you will be visiting every slot in `x`. Every time you add `.25` to the number in `x` at position `index`

Comment: Ohhhhh that explanation makes so much sense. Let me work with the code a bit, I think I can figure it out from here. Thank you so so much! :)

Comment: No problem! Happy coding! Also [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) is a helpful page when learning the basics.

Comment: Oh that looks great! Thank you!

Comment: Just because it sprung into my attention; "index <= num" -> "index < num" even better "index < x.length". HTH

Comment: Oh that makes sense, I was getting out of bound errors for the <= and the x.length is a lot cleaner. Thank you!